# #include errors detected in vscode in Centos

Tags: linux, centos, vscode-extensions

I try to run code in vscode but I got #include error...

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        cout << "Hola!!"
    }
```

[image: This what I am getting when I clicked on Bulv icon]

Comment: How have you configured VSCode for C++?

Comment: Using rpm package

Comment: No that's how you *installed* VSCode. You need to *configure* it as well. I recommend you read [this VSCode with C++ on Linux documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux). Especially [the section about C++ configuration with the `c_cpp_properties.json` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_cc-configurations).

Comment: By the way, you *have* installed the C++ compiler `g++`?